# Why Failed to start up libvirtd service in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

```
$ sudo systemctl status libvirtd
● libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-12-29 15:15:55 IST; 2min 49s ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
  Process: 21991 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21991 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 29 15:15:53 dell-latitude systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Dec 29 15:15:53 dell-latitude systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Dec 29 15:15:53 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: libvirt version: 1.3.1, package: 1ubuntu10.30 
(Guilherme G. Piccoli <gpiccoli@canonical.com> Wed, 26 Fe
Dec 29 15:15:53 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: hostname: dell-latitude
Dec 29 15:15:53 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: ignoring dangling symlink 
'/home/mshah/.steampath'
Dec 29 15:15:55 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 
'libvirt-qemu'
Dec 29 15:15:55 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: Initialization of QEMU state driver failed: 
invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'
Dec 29 15:15:55 dell-latitude libvirtd[21991]: Driver state initialization failed
```

I'm facing this issue on ubuntu16.04 and unable to run kvm. I'm also seeing the error

> Failed to connect socket to ‘/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock’:no such file or directory

when sent "virsh list --all" command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the libvirt QEMU driver has been configured to built to use the `libvirt-qemu` user account and that account does not exist in your `/etc/passwd` file.

NB, Ubuntu 16.04  / libvirt 1.3.1 are both very old, so I'd strongly recommend upgrading to a modern distro.